# html input type = number doesn't allow decimal points on certain droids

Tags: android, html

When an input is type = number, smart phones and tablets will automatically open the number keyboard when you click on the input field. However on the Samsung droid which I'm developing a website for, the number pad doesn't allow for decimals to be entered (the telephone dial pad opens). I'd like a number keyboard to appear that allows decimals. Any ideas?

The alphanumeric keyboard for the tablet has the numbers on the top (not a separate number section), which is making me lose hope that what I want is possible, but maybe y'all have some bright ideas.

Comment: In xml for an app, I use android:inputType="numberDecimal". Not sure if that's an html option on webpages, though.

Comment: What keyboard opens as a result to a mode is actually a choice of the keyboard, not the app.  The app specifies a mode and the keyboard decides the layout to match.  You get different behavior on Samsung because they have a different keyboard app by default.  You can play with the input type and see if it helps, but there is no way to force the keyboard to show a specific layout-  anything you pass it is a hint, not a requirement.

Comment: What attributes are you using? By default, `<input type=number>` allows integers only (`step=1`), so an implementation might well provide a UI that does not allow fractions. With `step=0.1` for example, the UI should allow a decimal separator.

Comment: I'm using `step = "any"`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, all that the `<input type = number>` is doing is calling on the keyboard to launch. What keyboard launches (stock, downloaded, emoji) and what subtype (number pad, QWERTY) is dependent on the keyboard app itself. Basically the stock keyboard is bringing up the numeric keypad but that keypad doesn't have a decimal which you want. If the end-user has another keyboard downloaded then that keyboard may have a different layout that includes a decimal on the numeric keypad. I know the keypad is your preferred choice but have you thought about just changing your code to calling on the QWERTY keyboard that has both numbers and the needed decimal? If a decimal is critical to what you want to accomplish I think that would be the best option.